# how to resolve 500 errors in javascript when calling json files with the post method type

Tags: javascript, html

I made a web service application that retrieves data from JSON with the post type method, but after it starts there is an error message, ERROR 500.

I tried to trace the error and found an explanation that the onClick command has a default GET method, not a post method, I tried adding the POST command on the HTML or javascript pages but it wasn't successful.

this is my HTML code, I really hope you can help me

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">-->

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">8271-Ternate</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Pencarian </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row mt-3 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1 class="text-center">Pencarian</h1>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Input a text..." id="search-input">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="search-button">search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <hr>

            <div class="row" id="nik-list">

            </div>

        </div>




<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS  -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"         integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my js code

```
function searchNIK(){
$('#nik-list').html('');
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/xxxx/get_json/xxx/xxx/get_nik',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 
    {
        'nik' : $('#search-input').val(),
        'user_id' : 'xxxxx',
        'password' : 'xxx',
        'ip_user' : 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    },
    success: function(result)
    {
        if (result.Response == "True")
        {
            let niks = result.Search;

            $.each(niks, function(i, data)
            {
                $('#nik-list').append(`
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="person.png" class="card-img-top"               alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">NIK</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">`+ data.NIK +`</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Nama Lengkap : `+ data.NAMA_LGKP +`</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kelurahan : `+ data.KEL_NAME+`</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">No KK : `+ data.NO_KK +`</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Tutup</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `);

            });

            $('#search-input').val('');

        } 
        else 
        {
            $('#nik-list').html(`
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="text-center">`+ result.Error +` </h1>
            </div>
            `)
        }
    }
});};    $('#search-button').on('click', function()   {
searchNIK();   });    $('#search-input').on('keyup', function(e){
if (e.keyCode === 13)
{
    searchNIK();
};});
```

but when I tried that JSON file using the RESTLET CLIENT, there was output data that was generated

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't come directly from your script but from the script of the Web service.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this
>   indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response.
>   Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500
>   status code with more details about the request to prevent the error
>   from happening again in the future.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500

The problem is probably generated by your data that you post with your ajax call. A data may be invalid and the server may not handle that correctly, generating this error 500.

Because it's an error from the server side, you will need access to the web service on the server if you want to know more about it. I can see that your call is on port 8080, so it's probably a Node.JS app. If you have access to this app, you will probably be able to better understand the source of the error.

Otherwise, I can only tell you to verify your data and if the JSON is valid.